# Div doesn't have height

Tags: html, css

Why does `wrapper` div not have a height? If I set the height (`height:200px`) the green background appears but how to set with auto height?

Here is my code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3xT4/1/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="effect"></div>   
   <div class="content">
       ...content
   </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    position: absolute; 
    background-color:red;
}

.wrapper, .effect {
  background: green;        
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 630px;
}

.effect {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q3xT4/2/ i try it but it doesnt work for me

Comment: Positioning an element absolutely removes it from the normal document flow. So, neither `.content` nor `.effect` will expand `.wrapper`.

Comment: Are you saying that `div.wrapper` doesn't have height, or that a div _inside_ the wrapper -- such as `div.effect` -- doesn't have height. It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not working (i.e. parent element not having any height) because all the immediate descendant of the `.wrapper` element is absolutely positioned — this will have the effect of taking them out of the flow of the document, therefore causing the parent's dimension to collapse to nothing.

> You will also notice that the [effect is the same when you float all
>   descendants](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/q3xT4/7/) of the parent wrapper, because `float` also has the
>   effect of taking normal elements out of the document flow.

There are only two ways to prevent this from happening, both of which involving declaring a certain height for the parent `.wrapper` element:

1. Either you explicitly state a height for the parent (see [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/q3xT4/5/))
2. Or use a relative height (say, in [percentages](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/q3xT4/7/) or [viewport units](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/q3xT4/6/)) that is not dependent on its own content.

You should reconsider your design strategy, and what you're trying to achieve. There is probably other ways to achieve what you intend to do, will you mind showing us?

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Very well explained!!